# Line chart in D3 is all over the place

Tags: javascript, d3.js

everyone! Currently trying to generate a line chart using D3 with a simple JSON data. I'm using [mbostock's line chart code](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245), I just change data.tsv with my own JSON file:

```
[
{"date":"Aug-14","close":"1"},
{"date":"Feb-14","close":"2"},
{"date":"Jan-14","close":"1"},
{"date":"Jul-14","close":"3"},
{"date":"Jun-14","close":"1"},
{"date":"Mar-14","close":"3"},
{"date":"May-14","close":"1"},
{"date":"Nov-14","close":"1"},
{"date":"Oct-14","close":"1"},
{"date":"Sep-14","close":"1"}
]
```

However, I get a graph that looks like [this crazy line chart](https://www.flickr.com/photos/127905058@N03/15701868767/)

And I have no idea why it's drawing the lines like that. Any input would be amazing!

Edit: Adding the current code I'm using.

```
<script>
//Setting up...
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("test.php", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
    console.log(d.date);
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without looking directly at your code, but you might not be passing a `Number` into your scale function. In the source code you copied, see:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
});
```

Or, just pass in data where `close` is a `Number`.

```
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
{"date":"Aug-14","close":1},
{"date":"Feb-14","close":2},
{"date":"Jan-14","close":1},
{"date":"Jul-14","close":3},
{"date":"Jun-14","close":1},
{"date":"Mar-14","close":3},
{"date":"May-14","close":1},
{"date":"Nov-14","close":1},
{"date":"Oct-14","close":1},
{"date":"Sep-14","close":1}
]
```

Edit:

Note also that the dates in the example you linked are sorted, yours are not.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b-%y").parse;

data.sort(function(a, b) { 
  return d3.ascending(parseDate(a.date), parseDate(b.date)); 
});
```

Comment: Added my code to the original question just now, haha! "close" is a number, I used parseInt on it too (though it can't be seen in my code right now) to make sure it's an integer. I think I know what's wrong though. My code starts by plotting using the first object (August), then goes to the second object (February) and so on. I'm not sure why I'm having this problem since in mbostock's code, their months are not in order either but their graph turns out fine.